# PySpark issues with loading unfit model object

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I was playing around with the `save` and `load` functions of `pyspark.ml.classification` models. I created an instance of a `RandomForestClassifier`, set values to a couple of parameters and called the `save` method of the classifier. It saves successfully. No issues there.

```py
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
# save
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
rf.setImpurity('entropy')
rf.setPredictionCol('predme')
rf.write().overwrite().save('rf_test')
```

Then I tried loading it back but I noticed that its parameters don't have the values I had set before saving. Below is the code I was trying

```py
# load
rf2 = RandomForestClassifier()
rf2.load('rf_test')
print(rf2.getImpurity()) # returns gini
print(rf2.getPredictionCol())  # returns prediction
```

I guess there's a difference in my understanding of how this code should work and how it actually works.

What should I do to get back the object the way I had saved it?

*EDIT*

I tried the approach mentioned here. But that didn't work. This is what I tried

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
rf.setImpurity('entropy')
rf.setPredictionCol('predme')
rf.write().overwrite().save('rf_test')
rf2 = RandomForestClassifier
rf2.load('rf_test')
print(rf2.getImpurity())
```

which returned the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: getImpurity() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you should use `load` method. It is a `classmethod` and should be called on a class object, not an instance, to return a new object:

```py
rf2 = RandomForestClassifier.load('rf_test')
rf2.getImpurity()
```

Technically speaking calling it on an instance would work as well, but it doesn't modify the caller, but returns a new independent object:

```py
rf2 = RandomForestClassifier().load('rf_test')
```

In practice though, such construct should be avoided.